# Pricing - Megabyte exchanged, analyzed and analyzed at edge

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, iot

Looking at the [IBM Bluemix Pricing Calculator](https://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/pricing) - specifically for Internet of Things - I noticed that, the pricing is driven by the data traffic. In terms of the calculator, it is the number of **megabytes (MiB ?) exchanged, analyzed and analyzed at edge**. Can you please let me know the definition of these terms and help me apply the same for the following scenarios?

**Scenario 1**

I have multiple devices and multiple rules registered on to the platform, where the rules send out emails. I am able to see the devices and its alerts on a board with some basic cards. Is this an example of message exchanged?

**Scenario 2**

I have multiple devices and multiple rules registered on to the platform, where the rules invoke a Node-RED flow. The Node-RED flow may possibly invoke other Bluemix services, 3rd party API, etc. Is this an example of message exchanged and analyzed?

**Scenario 3**

I have multiple devices and actions defined on to the platform for device management. The only interaction expected here is the push of some packages (configuration files, firmware patches, etc.) from Bluemix to device. Is this an example of message exchanged (and, possibly message analyzed at edge)?

**Scenario 4**

A particular device is set-up to acquire data every *n* number of seconds and per acquisition around 500 KiB of data is acquired. An edge agent is installed such that, only certain acquisitions that meet some criteria, is pushed to Bluemix. So, is this an example of message analyzed at edge?

Comment: This is best discussed with IBM Support or IBM Sales, not here on SO.

Comment: I had to come to SO as the suggested avenue didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

(Posted as answer instead of long comment)

I would suggest that you read the "terms" linked off the service (in the catalog: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/internet-of-things-platform):

Service Terms: http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/sla/bm-6738-03

That document details the charge metrics and defines the units used.

Comment: Thanks for the link to terms. It helps a bit. I have more questions; but, perhaps, a more detailed discussion would be fruitful.